# removing a class with a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

JQuery isn't removing class on click event so I added an event delegation but now code isn't working.

I'm trying to add a class to the active menu link and remove a class from the inactive menu links. Here is a link to the website: http://wildcanyongamesstats.com/?q=corporate/wahoo-fitness

I'm not sure how to remove the class from the inactive menu links. Can someone help?

Original that isn't removing class called "underline_active":

```
$(".c_men_1").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(standings).show();
    $(triathlon).hide();
    $(geocache).hide();
    $(challenges).hide();
    $(heat).hide();
    $(creek2peak).hide();

    localStorage.setItem('showStandings', 'true');
    localStorage.removeItem('showTriathlon');
    localStorage.removeItem('showGeocache');
    localStorage.removeItem('showChallenges');
    localStorage.removeItem('showHeat');
    localStorage.removeItem('showCreek2peak');
    $(".c_men_2, .c_men_3, .c_men_4, .c_men_5, .c_men_6").removeClass("underline-active");
    $(".c_men_1").addClass("underline_active");
});
```

Updated Code with a delegated event handler isn't working. The links are no longer clickable or interactive. Here is the code:

```
$( ".c_men_1" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(standings).show();
    $(triathlon).hide();
    $(geocache).hide();
    $(challenges).hide();
    $(heat).hide();
    $(creek2peak).hide();

    localStorage.setItem('showStandings', 'true');
    localStorage.removeItem('showTriathlon');
    localStorage.removeItem('showGeocache');
    localStorage.removeItem('showChallenges');
    localStorage.removeItem('showHeat');
    localStorage.removeItem('showCreek2peak');
    $(".c_men_2, .c_men_3, .c_men_4, .c_men_5, .c_men_6").removeClass("underline-active");
    $(".c_men_1").addClass("underline_active");
});
```

Here is a link to the JavaScript file: http://wildcanyongamesstats.com/sites/all/themes/wcg1/js/script.js?o7ecdx

Comment: In one case, it's called `underline-active` and in  the other case `underline_active`. This might be a reason

Comment: Yeah that fixed it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Is ".c_men_1" being created dynamically? If so, this will ensure the handler is re-usable:

```
$("body").on( "click", ".c_men_1", function() { ... });
```

"body" can be any parent of .c_men_1.

Comment: Put `.c_men` on the `body`? Thought this was a family friendly site :P

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the class being added is "underline_active", but the class being removed is "underline-active" (note the use of a hyphen vs. underscore.)  In the first example, try changing the removeClass() line to:

```
$(".c_men_2, .c_men_3, .c_men_4, .c_men_5, .c_men_6").removeClass("underline_active");
```